# How to add a column from a dataframe to another dataframe in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a data frame, say

```
val df = Seq(("a", "1"), ("b", "2")).toDF("A", "B")

+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  a|  1|
|  b|  2|
+---+---+
```

Another dataframe `df2` as

```
val df2 = Seq(("9"), ("10")).toDF("C")

+---+
|  C|
+---+
|  9|
| 10|
+---+
```

**How to make a new dataframe as below** :

```
A B C
a 1 9
b 2 10
```

It is guaranteed that both df and df2 will have same number of rows.

All of the internet articles are pointing towards joins, which is not the case that I want to do here. I want to add C as a primary key.

Comment: how many rows are we talking here in `df1` and `df2` ?

Comment: df1 and df2 could be in millions